# How to Work with JKS files in Golang Kafka-Go

Tags: go

**Background**

Connect with kafka cluster with tls configuration in Golang using Kafka-Go

**Steps to Follow**

Convert JKS Files into PEM files using following commands

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.server.truststore.jks -destkeystore server.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
$ openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -nokeys -out server.cer.pem

$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -destkeystore client.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
$ openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -nokeys -out client.cer.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out client.key.pem
```

**Code**

```
getKafkaReader(topic string) *kafka.Reader {

    kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
            Brokers:    brokers,
            GroupID:    id,
            Topic:       topic,
            Dialer:      getDialer(),
        })
    }
    return consumer
}

func getDialer() *kafka.Dialer {

    dialer := &kafka.Dialer{
        Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
        DualStack: true,
        TLS:       tlsConfig(),
    }

    return dialer
}

func tlsConfig() *tls.Config {

    // Keystore
    keys, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(kafkaConfig.KeyStoreLocation)
    blocks, err := p12.ToPEM(keys, kafkaConfig.KeyStorePassword)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    var pemData []byte
    for test, b := range blocks {
        _ = test
        pemData = append(pemData, pem.EncodeToMemory(b)...)
    }

    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(pemData, pemData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
   //Truststore
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client.key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        RootCAs:      caCertPool,
    }
    return config
}
```

**Error**
pkcs12: error reading P12 data: asn1: structure error: tags don't match

Anyone has idea or suggestion how to deal with this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read JKS files using [keystore-go](https://github.com/pavlo-v-chernykh/keystore-go). It only supports JKS store-type, which means that the new PKCS#12 store-type is not supported. You can see how I implemented it [here](https://github.com/mostafa/xk6-kafka/pull/209).